# Long established installation of postfix has become an open relay; how can I figure out how and stop it?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, e-mailrelay, fedora-server, fedora-37

This server system has been serving email services since `Red Hat v 1.1` (circa 1997 I think) and now is on Fedora Core 37; through many hardware and OS updates along the way it has been kept current. And, we chose `postfix` and `dovecot` early on, and are still using them. And I've been the system mangler all this time.

A week ago tomorrow we had our `/var` tree wiped out due to a bug in a backup script - doah! And it required a full rebuild of the OS, "from scratch", to the same version. All the software not included in the `Fedora Server 37` distribution was loaded fresh via `dnf install`. And, we got our full config back from our good backups.

On Monday, two days ago, I noticed the system was noticeably sluggish but didn't have time to look into it. And I also noticed our link to the internet seemed to have performance problems. That was a clue...

Then, I decided to get `spamassassin` working again - it takes time to configure a mature environment like this! And `SA` had been disabled before the loss of `/var`, so it didn't just start back up. And anyway, when I went to check `/etc/var/log/maillog` to see if it was doing its job, I found all these mail being relayed messages?! Whisky Tango Foxtrot?!

I then checked the mail queues - hundreds of thousand to Gmail alone! WOW!

For now, I've turned off ALL outbound emails with:

```
default_transport = error: Sorry spammers, we're not sending your email! So sue us!
```

And began trying to figure out what went wrong.

I DID find SOME were getting through claiming to be `127.0.0.1`, so I closed that down. And I methodically went through all the various (and copious) `postfix` configuration options and couldn't find a thing wrong...

So, I went to use one of these script-testing open-relay testing web sites that try a dozen or so different hacks that spammers use to convince otherwise well-configured servers to relay their mail, but I couldn't find any - the last time I looked, there were a half-dozen or so such web sites! (What happened to 'em?! If you know of one, please tell me!)

And so I used `nmap`. It does NOT do a comprehensive job, or if it can, I'm not familiar with how. But I turned to send back on and tested. In testing, it says:

```
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
rDNS record for <ip-addr>: <reverse-lookup-map>

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp  open     smtp
|_smtp-open-relay: Server doesn't seem to be an open relay, all tests failed
465/tcp filtered smtps
587/tcp open     submission
|_smtp-open-relay: Server isn't an open relay, authentication needed
MAC Address: [its mac address] (controller's mfg name)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 22.03 seconds
```

The ONLY two websites I could find to look at it and report were non-responsive - the one loaded but didn't respond and then when I tried reloading the page, it wouldn't reload, and the second kept saying it was busy, try again later.

So ... back to figuring it out "by hand."

OK, so NOW what do we do?

ALL requests for setting information will be gladly honored, but the config file is first of all huge, and secondly it contains a lot of private information we don't want out there.

**More information** - at anx's request, the output of `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 3.6
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 10
debug_peer_list = <past-not-current-external-ip>
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_transport = error: <our-middle-finger-to-spammers>
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 536870912
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
milter_default_action = accept
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, <list-of-60ish-domain-names>
mydomain = <primary-domain>
myhostname = mail.<primary-domain>
mynetworks = <list-of-5-internal-ips>
mynetworks_style = subnet
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
proxy_interfaces = <a-non-extant-external-ip-we-used-to-have>
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination, <list-of-11-internal-ips-most-don't-exist-now>
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/pop-before-smtp, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/pop-before-smtp, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<primary-domain-name>/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = $config_directory/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = $config_directory/dh512.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<primary-domain-name>/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
soft_bounce = no
strict_mailbox_ownership = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**More information** - most also at the request of anx:

- `Postfix` uses ports 25 (`smtp`) and 587 (`submission` or `msa`).
- `Dovecot` uses ports 993 (`imaps`) and 995 (`pop3s`) while it listens on 143 & 110 (`imap` / `pop`) which are blocked by (multiple) firewalls.

  postconf -M

  smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

  submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

  pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup

  cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup

  qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr

  tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr

  rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite

  bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce

  defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce

  trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce

  verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify

  flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush

  proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap

  proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap

  smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp

  relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name

  showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq

  error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error

  retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error

  discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard

  local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local

  virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual

  lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp

  anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil

  scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

  postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd

**Information yet to fetch:**

- What's in the "locally added received header"s.
- Analysis of postfix log "stack" for a given queue ID.

***HOLD THE PROGRAM!***

Simply HAVING to send a few vital emails out, but not wanting to give the spammers a single use of our systems, I decided to try just turning off `dovecot`... I found that turning off `dovecot` and restoring the `default_transport` setting allowed outbound to work normally and `Postfix` did **NOT** become an open relay! YAY!

SURE, it won't work for our non-local users (which number > 1 and < 100), but hey, "you gotta do what you gotta do..."

I think **this shifts the focus** considerably; **`dovecot` is THE issue.**

Comment: What does the locally added Received header say how the sender became authorized to submit? What do the postfix logs say about a queue ID that was found in the stack of unauthorized submissions? Any idea why it say "permit_mynetworks" twice in two quite meaningfully different positions in your restriction list? Are both 587 and 465 served by postfix, or is one a dovecot proxy (usually visible in the output of `postconf -M`)?

Comment: @anx As for your first question, IDK yet... About the received headers content, it's not something I've investigated before, or even realize I should! I will! Uh... I'll find that in the logs, or do I have to look at an example? The second, about queue ID, I don't really understand the question, unfortunately. I presume the "queue ID" is the inbound mail ID, easily found in the logs, and I guess by "stack" you mean the collective messages about an individual message? Presuming so, that's something I'll do soon. As for your question about "permit_mynetworks", I didn't realize that and...

Comment: @anx ...the reason is lost to history! Advice on that? As for the ports, ONLY through your asking did I learn that 587 WAS (not in config now) from dovecot - that's in the ".rpmsave" version of 10-master.conf! I take it I should put that back? So, I therefore presume it's coming from Postfix, but I don't see the number in the config, and neither it's /etc/services equivalent, "msa".  BUT, I have to get back to you with more - it;s late!

Comment: I don't recommend making such change now - that should only be executed after careful deliberation and review of affected options, I just know that if you had already opted into putting a dovecot proxy in front of postfix, from such changes a few incomplete configurations could arise that allow arbitrary public submissions to an xclient-enabled service. Such just don't exist in a configuration where exclusively postfix is handling submissions (`submission` and `smtps` are the commonly used port aliases in the first column of the postfix master configuration).

Comment: Look at the dates of configuration files, did you maybe put some old config back.. which is now wildcard-`include conf.d/*.conf` from a common file on top of your known-good files? Look at your postfix logs or the output of `postqueue -p`, the queue identifier looks something like `5F54EFCA0A`, that is what you can `grep` your logs for or ask `postcat -qhbe QUEUEID` to learn more about what is known about one particular message. In the postfix default configuration such ID is only assigned *after* accepting at least one recipient, but that is fine, your story sounds like this is the case.

Comment: Adding sample headers and the output of `postconf -M` might allow a clearer answer instead of just pointers & ideas.

Comment: @anx OK, update of question above done. Now on the hunt for the mail header data and "stack". We do not even have a conf.d - unique to Fedora Server? IDK. And so, there are no include statements - and yes, I checked. And I forgot to say that in the update. As for the queues, I didn't save them! I ran postsuper -d ALL - poof! - gigs of spam, gone in a flash! ... I can reopen and catch a few, if that's a good idea.

Comment: @anx, Just alerting you to the new realization that it's most likely a pure dovecot issue, though if I should fix the dual permit_mynetworks entries, I'd appreciate your thoughts on that. I can devote a good bit of attention to this today but also have some other vital work I must get to as well - so, I'll be "back and forth" at it. THANKS for your help!

Comment: Turning off dovecot solving anything smells like its the `permit_sasl_authenticated` method that allows submission, so possibly valid (just stolen/misused) credentials.

Comment: @anx At the time it was all coming inbound, I was looking at maillog and it DID talk about authentication being successful ... for accounts that clearly aren't ours! I kept the log. I also had some problem getting Dovecot restarted following the reinstallation. In short, I couldn't find the correct auth entry, so I took it from an older configuration file. MAYBE I should create a new question for this? ...Meanwhile, I've got some other critical work to do now - back at it soon. And I'll start investigating dovecot's auth issues ASAP.

Comment: @RohitGupta Hi editor Rohit, I approved the edits and wanted to comment:  Know that as someone who literally helped create the language we use here, first using the internet in 1978, LONG before web sites, your merging those words isn't in my vocabulary and maybe never will be, my use of commas is more old-school than yours, perfectly valid and neither is better here, and your other two edits, well, just style differences; however, if all that helps reach people, SURE! And thanks for caring!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now convinced it was not a `Postfix` issue but a `Dovecot` issue. However, this answer may well be helpful to others.

In particular, how to determine it was likely not a `Postfix` issue was a bigger learning curve than I expected for being someone who's used the same system (as a system admin) literally for two decades and then some.

What I hadn't realized was that with this kind of configuration, `Postfix` itself "gives up authority control" to `Dovecot`. And, well, at this point, `Dovecot`'s ability to receive valid connections from those of us who are not in the internal network except when we're on-site has become an important feature of our functioning.

Thankfully, it's less vital for us than for many other organizations as we have other alternatives, but the reality is that most don't want to bother to log-in via command line just to deal with mail - I suspect this is the most popular position! - in this circumstance! But that takes nothing away from recognizing what I had not:

**You cannot just stop `Dovecot`, once configured, and expect to be able to send WITHOUT reconfiguring `Postfix` to not use `Dovecot`. And, you can't even just block the ports to `Dovecot` from the outside, because `Postfix` will just call `Dovecot` directly anyway!**

**Ultimately, as per my understanding (glad to be proven wrong!) once configured, `Postfix` gives up darned near all security authority for any connection that pretends to be a valid user to `Dovecot`, though all "internal" sends and receives function normally with `Dovecot` running and `Postfix` prevented from sending (as described in the question).**

I figure it's both fruitless and inappropriate to use this question to ask about `Dovecot`'s issues, and while I think these comments constitute a valid answer, I will need to ask another question about `Dovecot` because *"I'll be damned if I can find what's wrong!"*

I strongly suspect either I'm making a (likely not uncommon) gaff OR, there's a bug in the version we have now, post rebuild, as the config before reload was NOT sending spam, and that's what we had been using for several days before the spammers began using our system! **Notably, when we didn't stop `Postfix` from sending, NO external system we found / used to test our system thinks our system is an open mail relay but there's NO denying it relayed hundreds of thousand of emails improperly!** Further, opening it back up (permitting Postfix to send) promptly allowed

Worth citing here is that I have checked the logs and, with the limited time I have, given all the demands on me at present, I **have with 90%+ certainty confirmed that there's no "stolen credentials," but that has yet to be proven.** I sure don't see the evidence in the logs, though I'm not keen to open up to the spammers again with new logging configuration to gain more data. **PERHAPS it's worth always having maximum authorization logging for just this reason!**